# Addition in tuple list

Tags: algorithm, haskell, tuples

I'm tring to write a function called maxTotal which will take a list of tuples as a parameter, where each tuple in the list   consists   of   three    Ints.     I need to  find   the   tuple   whose   total   (the   sum   of   the   3 integers in the tuple) is greatest and return that total.

```
example:
*Main> maxTotal [(1,2,3),(7,4,2),(5,5,1)]
13
*Main> maxTotal [(1,2,3),(5,5,1),(3,15,0)]
18
*Main> maxTotal [(3,3,3)]
9
```

This is what I have:

```
tuplesum :: (Num a) => [(a,a,a)] -> [a] 
tuplesum  [] = []
tuplesum  ((a,b,c):xs) = (a+b+c) : tuplesum  xs
maxTotal::(Num a) =>[(a,a,a)]->a
maxTotal[]=error"empty list"
maxTotal tuplesum (head : tail) = max head (maxTotal tail)
```

My tuplesum works but I keep getting errors saying "parse error on input ‘=’"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import Data.List

tuplesum :: (Num a) => [(a,a,a)] -> [a] 
tuplesum x = [a+b+c|(a,b,c)<-x]
maxTotal::(Num a, Ord a) =>[(a,a,a)]->Maybe a
maxTotal [] =Nothing
maxTotal x = Just (maximum $ tuplesum x)
```

Or if you like it even shorter:

```
import Data.List

maxTotal::(Num a, Ord a) =>[(a,a,a)]->Maybe a
maxTotal [] = Nothing
maxTotal x = Just (maximum [a+b+c|(a,b,c)<-x])
```

If you don't like Maybe you can use:

```
import Data.List

maxTotal::(Num a, Ord a) =>[(a,a,a)]->a
maxTotal x = maximum [a+b+c|(a,b,c)<-x]
```

It already gives an error for the empty list.

Comment: is there anyway to do it without using Maybe?

Comment: I found the second code works the same even if I deleted Maybe and Just, are they really necessary?

Comment: The Maybe type is used to indicate a failure and is quite useful. In the last code the program just crashes if something went wrong. In the second example one can test if there is a value `Just 4` or if there is `Nothing´. Normally you just don't want your program to crash due to bad inputs.

Comment: I like the third code the most but I never learnt $, in fact I'm supposed to use Maybe/Just/$ cause they are not in my course scope, anyway to change the 3rd code a little bit so I don't have to use $?

Comment: `maximum $ [a+b+c|(a,b,c)<-x]` is the same like `maximum ([a+b+c|(a,b,c)<-x])`. But in this case you might even drop the parenthesis completely.

Comment: yes,it works without $,but I got several errors when I deleted the $ in the first code

Comment: Of course. There you have to replace `maximum $ tuplesum x` by `maximum (tuplesum x)`. An alternative might be `(maximum . tuplesum) x`, which is concatenation of functions.